# file not found exception after file renamed android,JAVA

Tags: java, android

I am trying to rename the file before uploading it to the server....The file is getting renamed, but it is throwing a `fileNotFoundException`. Please help

```
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        DataOutputStream dos;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
        int maxSize = 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(fileuri);
        final String name = fileuri.substring(fileuri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        String directory = fileuri.replace(name, "");
        File to = new File(directory, filename);
        sourceFile.renameTo(to);
        String path=sourceFile.getPath().toString();
        final long length = sourceFile.length();
        if (length / maxSize > 1) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Larger than 1MB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return 0;
        }

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {


            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + imagepath);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Source File not exist :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return 0;`
```

Comment: Post the logcat, file name, file location, project structure... please

Comment: Can you post the line number on which you got the exception?

Comment: String path=sourceFile.getPath().toString(); it still shows the old file path....@PiyushShrivastava

Comment: sourceFile.renameTo(to);
Print/log this line. You will get a boolean value. True if file is renamed successfully.

Comment: @PiyushShrivastava it shows true

Comment: Can you post the output of `to.getPath().toString()`, also the values of `name` and `directory`

Comment: @AyushBhawsar,  can you answer your own question and tell us how you solved it?

Comment: i had to overwrite the fileuri i.e. uri of the file which was pointing to the file before it was renamed so was getting the file not found exception....@PiyushShrivastava